# How to sync database with electronjs

Tags: javascript, architecture, electron

I would like to use electronjs to develop a desktop application. The app has to have an offline and online database, such that when the system connects to the Internet, the databases can sync.. How can I achieve this please. Using nodejs to develop apis

Comment: This question is extremely broad and has many facets. I would suggest looking else where for intro tutorials on ElectronJs, and NodeJs. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that with sqlite database or pouchDB. If you don't want to write long queries for sqlite then you can use [Prisma sqlite](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/sqlite#overview). then after just store it in the local database (sqlite or pouchDB) whenever the system is offline. and whenever the system will become online post the last data to your SQL/Postgres/Mongo server.